# AWS Managed Grafana is not allow property of allow_embedding?

Tags: amazon-web-services, charts, devops, grafana, dashboard

I want to use Iframe from grafana aws managed, but I am not able to edit grafana configuration file, How can we update AWS managed grafana conf.

[sample question asked on AWS](https://repost.aws/questions/QUHV1D-liKSKmeCqje1gclIA/amazon-grafana-embed-panels-not-working-due-to-x-frame-options-deny-on-iframes)
Receiving this error.
[image: response after changing request]

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That's the concept of a managed service. As of today, I could not find this parameter exposed in AWS. Maybe in the future